# Close DIV when parent's clicked, but not from its children

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://liveweave.com/lJu0ng

When the textbox is focused/mousedown/touchstart you're able to change an elements font-family. Either by typing or clicking the font button from the bubble that's visible upon focusin.

I want to close the bubble when toolbox is clicked, but but when the bubble (not bubble's children) are clicked.

How can I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Check the event target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, working with your latest code:

http://liveweave.com/mvxPkl

I added class="font" to the font tags and check that e.target does not have class "font"

```
 $(".toolbox").on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('font')){
         $(this).children().not($("input[type=text]")).hide();      
    } 

  });
```

Comment: I spent 3 hours yesterday and 2 today trying to get this to work (without counting the research I did) and you did this in a few minutes just with `if (!$(e.target).hasClass('font')){`. Lol I feel flabbergasted. I gotta start reviewing the JQuery API's more